# How can I label the pie charts in QGIS so the labels are written under the diagrams?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

How can I label the pie charts in QGIS so the labels are written under the diagrams? My pie-charts are representing localities: such as villages, towns, cities. So, I want that their names appear under the diagrams. I want them to look like this image

[image: I want them to look like this image]

Comment: Use easy label
so it create a shp with label

Comment: I've removed the second question. Please note that each thread on this site is supposed to contain only one question and its answers. Feel free to open a second thread for your other answer.